# Fill a table from a list C# asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table

I have a class `Car`, with some atributtes `Model` and `Year`. I have a list (`List<Car> carList = new List<Car>()`) of some objects of the class `Car`, and I want to put this list into an HTML tag , but I have no idea how to do this.

I got a template that already has a `<table>`, that's why I'm trying to use `<table>` instead of `<asp:GridView>`.

I'm using WebForms

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically add rows to a table in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789240/how-to-dynamically-add-rows-to-a-table-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are set on using a `<table>` and not any of the `<asp:*>` controls, you can manually build your markup on the page.

First, you need to be able to access the object from your markup.  By making it a `protected` (or `public`) property on the code-behind, the page can access it:

```
protected IList<Car> CarList { get { return carList; } }
```

Then in the page (which inherits from the code-behind class) you can access that property to build markup.  Something like this:

```
<% foreach (var car in CarList) { %>

<% } %>
```

Inside of that loop would be your rows, outside would be your table dressing.  Something like this, perhaps:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column Heading</th>
  </tr>
<% foreach (var car in CarList) { %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= car.SomeValue %></td>
  </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

This is *similar* to how one may construct markup in MVC, so you can think of it like that.  Though it's not common for WebForms and it's often recommended to use the framework the way it's meant to be used.  In the long run, if you're set on using WebForms, it may be less work to adjust the template to work with the server-side controls than to manually build the markup.  The server-side controls have the added benefit of lots of event binding and code-behind interactions.

Comment: ListView control ?