# How can I populate an HTML table with data from a generic list in a Webforms app?

Tags: html, razor, webforms, generic-list

Based on an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868589/fill-a-table-from-a-list-c-sharp-asp-net) by Goliath-slayer, I tried the following to get data from my generic list into an html table:

```
<table width="100%" id="my-grid" class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Year</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var book in booksList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@book.Title</td>
                <td>@book.Category</td>
                <td>@book.PublishYear</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

...but all I get is this:

[image]

In more context, here is the class:

```
namespace HTML5AndBootstrap4Sandbox
{
    public class SandboxData
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public int PublishYear { get; set; } // int so that it can be ordered
    }

}
```

...and the hydration of an instance of a generic list of the class:

```
namespace HTML5AndBootstrap4Sandbox
{
    public class DataUtils
    {
        protected IList<SandboxData> booksList { get { return GetSandboxData(); } }

        private List<SandboxData> GetSandboxData()
        {
            List<SandboxData> sbdList = new List<SandboxData>();

            SandboxData sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "The Innocents Abroad";
            sbd.Category = "Nonfiction";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1869;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "Roughing It";
            sbd.Category = "Nonfiction";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1872;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "A Tramp Abroad";
            sbd.Category = "Nonfiction";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1880;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "Life on the Mississippi";
            sbd.Category = "Nonfiction";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1883;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "Following the Equator";
            sbd.Category = "Nonfiction";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1897;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "King Leopold's Soliloquy";
            sbd.Category = "Essay";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1905;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "The Gilded Age: A Tale of Today";
            sbd.Category = "Novel";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1873;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer";
            sbd.Category = "Novel";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1876;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "The Prince and the Pauper";
            sbd.Category = "Novel";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1881;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "Adventures of Huckleberry Finn";
            sbd.Category = "Novel";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1884;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court";
            sbd.Category = "Novel";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1889;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "The American Claimant";
            sbd.Category = "Novel";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1892;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "Pudd'nhead Wilson";
            sbd.Category = "Novel";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1894;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "Extracts from Adam's Diary";
            sbd.Category = "Short Story";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1904;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "The War Prayer";
            sbd.Category = "Short Story";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1905;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            sbd = new SandboxData();
            sbd.Title = "To the Person Sitting in Darkness";
            sbd.Category = "Essay";
            sbd.PublishYear = 1901;
            sbdList.Add(sbd);

            return sbdList;
        }

    }
}
```

What am I missing/misapplying/misunderstanding that's preventing me from seeing this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you output, it looks that your Razor code is not interpreted. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264852/can-we-use-razor-syntax-in-asp-net-webforms-aspx-pages) deals with how to use Razor syntax within a ASP forms application:

If you have a simple page (no forms controls) you can just put `.cshtml` or `.vbhtml` extension and the syntax should work.

For more complex scenarios you may consider working with [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/), but you will no get all the goodies of the full fledged Razor Engine from ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I don't know what you mean - where in my code above would I put ".cshtml"?

Comment: `.cshtml` should be used instead of `.aspx` (the view).