# add row to asp table of dynamic user controls in updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an `<asp:Table>` with rows that are made dynamically; where each `cell` has a user control. On an `<asp:Button>` click I call a function that adds another row of user control's to the table using the table's `ID` in the code behind. The problem is that it only ever adds one row to the table. This could be because the data doesn't persist or other reasons *(I'm not too sure)*.

## .ascx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel 
    ID="UpdatePanel1"
    UpdateMode="Conditional"
    runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <!-- Table update/add -->
        <div class="table-controls">
            <asp:button type="button" class="ui left floated positive button" runat="server" OnClick="TableAdd_OnClick" Text="New Row">
            </asp:button>

            <asp:button type="button" class="ui right floated positive button" runat="server" OnClick="TableSave_OnClick" Text="Save">
            </asp:button>
        </div>
        <!-- Table update/add -->

        <!-- Flex Table -->
        <asp:Table
            ID="Table"
            class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover sortable"
            Style="width: 100%; margin-top: 0; padding-top: 0; overflow: auto;"     
            runat="server">

            <asp:TableHeaderRow
                ID="TableHeader"
                Style="color: White; background-color: #2E2E2E;"
                runat="server">
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>

            <!-- Dynamic User Controls -->

            <asp:TableFooterRow>
            </asp:TableFooterRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <!-- Flex Table -->
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

## .ascx.cs (codebehind)

```
protected void TableAdd_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var tr = new TableRow();
        foreach (var col in DataSource)
        {
            var td = new TableCell();

            switch (col.Item1)
            {
                case "Type":
                    td.Controls.Add(col.Item3(""));
                    break;
                case "Account Name":
                    td.Controls.Add(col.Item3(""));
                    break;
                case "Applications":
                    td.Controls.Add(col.Item3(""));
                    break;
                case "Accounting Date":
                    td.Controls.Add(col.Item3(""));
                    break;
                case "Post Date":
                    td.Controls.Add(col.Item3(""));
                    break;
                case "Amount":
                    td.Controls.Add(col.Item3(""));
                    break;
                case "":
                    td.Controls.Add(col.Item3(""));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }

            tr.Cells.Add(td);

        }

        Table.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
```

## question

How can update this table so that on each click it actually adds a new row. I looked into using `ChildControlsCreated`, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it to fix this issue.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789358/). Although it is more complex, this sort of thing usually turns out much better if the [rows are added with AJAX](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/145c93/adding-dynamic-rows-in-html-table-with-textboxes-and-with-de/).

Comment: @NightOwl888 I had it like that before, but on postback's the table's rows/deletes would disappear and some of the user controls in the row's need to postback. This is why I'm trying do the row adds/deletes in the postback.

Comment: I guess you have to recreate the whole table in this event and also add the new row and also previous rows you might have added...